# In android memory monitor, what is the different between `total count` and `heap count`?

Tags: android

In [google docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-hprof.html), it said that,`heap count` means Number of instances in the selected heap,while `total count` means Total number of instances outstanding.What is the selected heap? Always, the `total count` is larger than `heap count`,so ,where is the other objects besides those in heap?

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 heaps in Android:

- App
- Image
- Zygote

`Total Count` is the total across all 3 heaps. `Heap Count` is the number of objects in the current selected heap.

See https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-hprof.html

Answer (score 1):

total count include the instance in running stack too.
heap count is just in heap size.

Comment: Not sure there is such thing as a stack memory space for objects in android. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/65281/stack-and-heap-memory-in-java